# iTunes freeze when on podcasts tab

Tags: itunes, podcasts, performance

I have a problem with the latest itunes 10.2  When I hit itunes podcast tab it freezes. I found a workaround by creating new library, but it's annoying that every time I had to recreate my library to just got freeze again in new library.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Operating System: on PC Window xp sp2

iTunes version: 10.2.2.14

Comment: Are you referring to the downloaded podcasts or the iTunes store podcast "shopping" directory?

Comment: @bmike, downloaded podcasts

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible workaround myself. Firstly cut off internet connection of your computer, then open iTunes, hit Podcasts tab, then iTunes will hang for a while but not complete freeze, delete suspected podcasts that may cause freeze, lastly reestablish internet connection.

Comment: Good isolation of the issue - if the network delay is long, it might not handle delays well or report them to you just as the link to the App Store hanging when certificate revocation lists are being checked. On fast computers today, the only thing slower than waiting for a slow hard drive is the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Look a [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13560/mac-app-store-has-become-dog-slow-after-10-6-7-update-on-latest-macbook-pro/14787#14787). The two problems are oddly similar, even though it's not the same app.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to "List" instead of "Unplayed, my podcasts and my stations".