# App Store is insanely slow on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm not sure if it is a problem with Lion, but my App Store is insanely slow.

I Googled and tried the solutions available online, but none of them work.

And I just keep seeing the beach ball.

One thing I noticed is, on my Mac, when I click "see all" in the App Store, the list of apps first show in 3 columns, and after a while of beach ball, it becomes 4 columns. That's different from other people's video showing slow app store. (in their video, it is automatically 4 columns.)

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Is there solution available?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13560/mac-app-store-has-become-dog-slow-after-10-6-7-update-on-latest-macbook-pro

Comment: yes, i did. Doesn't work.

Comment: I observed the slowness once I installed more Apps from the Mac App Store. Retrieving information from the Purchases tab is the slowest one for me.

Comment: App Store is slow because is just a browser for HTML content. Just like iTunes Store.

Comment: I noticed a considerable improvements with the release of 10.7.2 update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a specific problem with this, but generally when I have an issue of an App running slow, I blame corrupt cache/preference files. What I would recommend is using an App like AppZapper. You can use a free trail from: http://www.appzapper.com/downloads/appzapper.dmg which will last for 10 "zaps"

I would recommend you drag App Store.app into AppZapper, and delete all files BUT App Store.app. Do so by UNCHECKING THE BOX beside App Store.app. On the next launch of the Mac App Store, it'll recreate these (possible corrupt) preference/cache files and hopefully fix your slowness problem :)

[image]

Comment: `rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/; rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist; rm  ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist.lockfile`

Comment: LOl i guess that works too :P